# Android NDK Capturing Key Events

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I have an Android NDK game (NDK 4.) Almost all of the code is in C++ (it's a port) so in the Java all I have is an Activity and a GLSurfaceView with an override for onTouchEvents.  I'm trying to figure out how to receive key press events so that I can forward them on to the native code to be handled.

I tried having the View implement OnKeyListener but onKey() is never called. Also tried overriding the onKeyDown() and onKeyUp() in the View with no success. Am I missing something?

**Update**

The View as I'm currently using it:

```
public class FooView extends GLSurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, OnKeyListener
{
    private GameRenderer _renderer;
    private GameListener _listener;

    public FooView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        this._renderer = new GameRenderer();
        setRenderer(this._renderer);
        this._listener = new GameListener(context);
        BaseLib.setListener(this._listener);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event)
    {
        // touch code...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        Log.d("testing", "onKeyDown event from Java");
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        Log.d("testing", "onKeyUp event from Java");
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        Log.d("testing", "onKey event from Java");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to pass (this) to the view as you add the event listener (assuming your activity implements onKeyListener)

Comment: Could you post some of the java side code you are using, particularly where you're seeing the OnKeyListener? Assuming Dr. Dredel's suggestion wasn't the issue.

Comment: The onKeyDown and Up there should be working...

Comment: @Maximus That's what I expected but I'm not seeing anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
  @Override
  public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
  {
          //
          // SEND event.getAction() to your NDK code
          //
          if(<NDK CODE PROCESSED IT>) return true;

          // default behavior for everything else
          return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
  }
```

Comment: What is the overhead of going through JNI for every character typed on the keyboard? I'm finding that there is a huge overhead for this.

Comment: There is definitely a cost to the JNI calls, but I wouldn't expect it to be THAT high: I'd expect if you're seeing unexpected delays it may either be a platform issue (perhaps an issue with the emulator?) or your code may be doing a lot of work to process the keystrokes. Hard to tell without more detail. That said, I think newer Android platforms support entirely native activity implementations with no Java layer (https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_na): you may get more out of that.

Answer (score 0):

(typing from memory, so the syntax may not be 100%, but... )as per my comment... are you doing this... ?

class myAct extends Activity implements View.onKeyListener

myButton.setOnKeyListener(this)

Comment: I don't have a button to attach to. The OpenGL draws directly to the surface. So it looks like my problem is I need to call setOnKeyListener() on something. Can I do that with the view itself?